# Non-deterministic Cucumber Test Failures for Consecutive Ajax Requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, integration-testing

We have a standard cucumber integration test stack using

- Ruby v.1.9.3,
- Rails v.3.2.13
- Capybara v.2.1.0
- Capybara-Webkit v.1.0.0
- FactoryGirl v.4.2.1

We have recently had problem where a collection of scenarios involving multiple consecutive ajax requests are failing sporadically with the following error:

```
    Capybara::Webkit::NodeNotAttachedError (Capybara::Webkit::NodeNotAttachedError)
    ./features/step_definitions/patient_steps.rb:133:in `/^I should see the followin
    g patient names in this order:$/'
    features\searching_patients_index.feature:39:in `Then I should see the following
    patient names in this order:'
```

The interesting part is that this error is only being thrown on a Windows machine.

The most typical responses to this problem have been:

- enforcing some sort of sleep or wait_until (despite it's deprecation, we reverted to Capybara v.1.1.3 to try it still) but this has not helped.
- we tried increasing the default Capybara wait time
- we have tried a "wait until **_** is visible" by checking if a particular piece of the DOM is visible

  ```
  When(/^I wait until "(.*?)" is visible$/) do |selector|
    page.has_css?("#{selector}", :visible => true)
  end
  ```

Here is an example of one of the failing features:

```
    Scenario: Searching and then sorting patients
      When I search for "J"
      And I click on the "Name" header in the "patients" table
      And I wait until ".patient.odd" is visible
      Then I should see the following patient names in this order:
        | names       |
        | Smith, John |
        | Schmo, Jill |
      Then the result content should not include "Drapper, Don"
```

We are using Ajax for both searching a table and sorting it by column, so we are testing if the searching persists when sorting, in this example.

Please let us know if we can provide any further context and thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after each ajax request starts

```
 And I wait for the ajax request to finish

 Given /^I wait for the ajax request to finish$/ do
   start_time = Time.now
   result = false
   while result ==  false do
     result = page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active === 0')
     if Time.now >= start_time + 5.seconds
       result = true
     else
       sleep 0.5
     end
   end
   sleep 0.5
 end
```

This works for what I'm doing. I haven't used it for sorting columns on the page though. As long as the ajax request is waiting for a response from the controller then it *should* work

Comment: Shouldn't the `>=` be a `<`? That condition is now true the first time throught the loop unless evaluating the javascript took more than 5 seconds, which seems unlikely.

Comment: I see what you're saying. I should add a sleep of .5 seconds right after I set the value of start_time. That will prevent the chance of the check ending prematurely.

Comment: After .5 seconds, start_time + 5.seconds will still always be >= Time.now.

Comment: HA, yes I had it backwards.